# Hook on trash post

Tags: hooks

I want to perform an action when I delete one of my custom post types, which hook should I use:

```
wp_trash_mycpt
```

or

```
trash_mycpt
```

My action should run solely when **`mycpt`** is in the `'publish', 'draft' or 'future'` state and moves towards the 'trash' state. When it is removed from trash itself there is no reason to run the function again.

Answer (score 12):

The [`wp_trash_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_trash_post/) hook might be what you're looking for:

> Fires before a post is sent to the trash.

Also, there's the [`trashed_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/trashed_post/) hook:

> Fires after a post is sent to the trash.

Here's some untested code to get you started:

```
function my_wp_trash_post( $post_id ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );
    if ( $post_type == 'mycpt' && in_array(
        $post_status, array( 'publish','draft','future' )
    )) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'my_wp_trash_post' );
```

Comment: Doesn't the function `wp_trash_post()` change the `post_status` to `trash` before calling the `wp_trash_post` hook?

Comment: Nope, after. Just [look at the code](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_trash_post?version=3.5&file=wp-includes/post.php).

Comment: Good that's been changed then. I remember looking at this a couple of years back and that was not the case!

Comment: @dalbaeb I've been using trash_post hook till now, what's the difference between that and wp_trash_post?

Comment: Also wouldn't it be better to use wp_trash_mycpt rather than checking for the post type within the function?

Comment: @drtanz Because `trash_post` is deprecated. Also, I can't find a variable hook for this kind of action (you got a link?), so `wp_trash_post` is really the best one you've got.

Comment: Here's a related ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15628

I'm actually using trash_mycpt in my plugin and it works fine, so I assumed wp_trash_mycpt would also work.

Comment: The link doesn't mention `trash_mycpt` anywhere. Ok, so if all is working fine then pray tell, what was the point of your question?

Answer (score 4):

Run your function when post status changes from any of `publish`, `draft` or `future` to `trash`.

```
<?php
function my_function() {
    global $post;
    if('my_post_type' == $post->post_type) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}

add_action('publish_to_trash', 'my_function');
add_action('draft_to_trash',   'my_function');
add_action('future_to_trash',  'my_function');
```

More info: [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

Comment: These are useful, but I think wp_trash_post/trash_post will do fine in my case as I don't need this level of control actually.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `wp_trash_post` action that is called, but the `post_status` is changed to `trash` beforehand, meaning you would not be able to check whether the Post was published, etc.

**EDIT** I stand corrected, the `post_status` is changed to `trash` AFTER the action is called.

This should get you started however -

```
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'my_wp_trash_post')
function my_wp_trash_post(){

    if($post->post_type === 'mycpt') :
        // Do what ever you need to do here
    endif;

}
```

If it is of any use, there is also an `delete_post` action. For more information, see the Action Reference for [`delete_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use wp_trash_mycpt rather than checking for the post type within the function?